# Runtime.exec() Java to run cmd script

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to use Runtime to run a simple cmd script. Below I have two examples. When I run the command strings by hand in a cmd shell, they produce the desired result. When I run this program, command 1 works, and command 2 does not. Is there any particular reason why the second command wouldn't work through java while the first does?

No error messages or exceptions.

EDIT: The second command works if I add an execution log, i.e. change it to the line below. Why would that be?

`String cmd2 = "C:/Users/evans/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Repricer/RunDownload.cmd >> log.txt";`

The execution log is this:

```
// Execution log
C:\Users\evans\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Test>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Users\evans\Documents\Book Business\Building Reports\Book Business.accdb" /x Download  

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // 1
            String cmd = "wscript C:/Users/evans/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Repricer/RunExcel.vbs DownloadExcel";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", cmd} );

            // 2    
            String cmd2 = "C:/Users/evans/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Repricer/RunDownload.cmd";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", cmd2} );
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any error-messages or exceptions?

Comment: You should at least provide execution log of RunDownload.cmd. Modify your command to output to a file. "C:/Users/evans/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Repricer/RunDownload.cmd >>log.txt"

Comment: When you run those two scripts directly on the command line; using the given arguments ... do they both work there?

Comment: Yes, they both work on the command line, just not through the Java program. I just discovered that the second script works if I add `>>log.txt` on the end. I don't know why that would be.